# Tabularx table where every row has multicolumn alignment issues without adding an extra line

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I am trying to create a table in tex where each row is made up of some combination of merged cells.

When I generate the table it looks great as long as I add an extra row:
[image]

However I do not want the extra row on the end but when I remove it from the code the alignment is no longer correct.

[image]

What can I do to fix this?  Here is the basic code I am using.

I am very new to to this so any help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage{tabularx} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|} {Hello} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|} {Hello} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Bye}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|} {Hello} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Bye}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|} {Hello} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Bye}\\ \hline
%&&&\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no effective `X` columns.

If you add a fake row without `|` you can back up over it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage{tabularx} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X}
\multicolumn{1}{X}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{X}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{X}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{X}{}\\[-\baselineskip]
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|} {Hello} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|} {Hello} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Bye}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|} {Hello} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Bye}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|} {Hello} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Bye}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it perfectly plus it adds that one row as white space so when I start my text under the table it has a nice clean gap!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]}[hvlines]
\Block{1-4}{Hello} \\
\Block{1-2}{Hello} && \Block{1-2}{Bye} \\
\Block{1-3}{Hello} &&& Bye \\
Hello & \Block{1-3}{Bye}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]